# UNITY - Infinite Jump

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have an issue with a script in Unity 2D, because my character infinitely jump, can you help me please (I'm a noob in Unity).
I have tried a thing with a boolean but no results...
My code in C# is :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Movements2D : MonoBehaviour {

    public float movementSpeed = 5.0f;
    private float jumpHeight = 500f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKey("left") || Input.GetKey("q"))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.left * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if(Input.GetKey("right") || Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") || Input.GetKey("z"))
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce (new Vector3 (0, jumpHeight, 0), ForceMode.Force);
    }


}
```

Thanks for your help,

Flo.

Comment: I'm not sure if problem is that it continues to fly forever? Do you have rigidbody.useGravity enabled (or rigidbody2d gravityscale not zero)?

Comment: And note there is difference with "jump" and "z" key behaviour at the moment. When "jump" is pushed down Jump() will execute once even when "jump" is held down. While z key is held down Jump() is executed every frame until key is released. If you want similar behaviour for both you can use Input.GetKeyDown("z").

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking that your character is on the floor before adding the force that causes them to go upwards. This check is often done using a [`Raycast`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html). So perhaps something like:

```
void Jump()
{
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up, 0.1f);
    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce (new Vector3 (0, jumpHeight, 0), ForceMode.Force);
    }
}
```

That will cast a ray downwards from the current position of the character up to a maximum distance of 0.1 (which you may wish to change). If the ray hit anything then the character must be on (or very close to) the floor and so may jump.

Comment: Maybe because it is used in "void FixedUpdate()" in this example